# Is the "127 Corridor Sale" the world's longest yard sale?

Tags: geography

[These](http://www.127sale.com/) folks claim to organize the "World's Longest Yard Sale" every year.

It claims to run from Hudson, Michigan to Gadsden, Alabama following US 127. I can attest that folks on Lookout Mountain, Georgia participate every year. I am wondering if this claim to the world's longest yard sale is valid.

Comment: I suspect this will have definition issues, so I looked up Wikipedia's take: 'A garage sale, also known as a yard sale, rummage sale, tag sale, attic sale, moving sale, or junk sale, is an informal, **irregularly scheduled** event for the sale of used goods by private individuals, in which "block sales" are allowed, so that sellers are not required to obtain business licenses or collect sales tax.' 127 Corridor Sale is scheduled regularly, and therefore not a yard sale! :-)

Comment: I think India has the longest yard sale.

Comment: There are also homes that do not participate.... in Hong Kong there is a night market that snakes through alleys in Kowloon for about 1 subway stop long -- say 200 yards of one table after another.  Since it is continuous, whose to say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find a reference on the Guiness World Records web site, but [this news article](http://www.albanyherald.com/home/headlines/92151264.html) from 2010 says:

> And if you were wondering, according to the Guinness Book of World
>   Records, The World’s Longest Yard Sale” runs along a 630-mile stretch
>   of U.S. Highway 127 from Gadsden, Ala. to Covington, Ky.

Here is some [more evidence](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/Yard+sale+stretches+52+miles.-a0118908314) pointing to the Guiness World Record in 2004:

> Contrary to the hopes of some participants, this sale won't even come
>   close to breaking the Guinness World Record for longest yard sale.
>
> "No, no," Weiler said. "There's a 450-mile yard sale on Highway 27
>   that runs through four states in the South - that's where I got the
>   idea for this one."

Comment: It should be noted that Guinness change the records they list each year, so it may disappear from the modern books without having been beaten.